# Can an undefined function be said to be not convex?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Is there a formal argument as to whether or not an undefined function can be considered "not convex?"

I think this is practically analogous to saying that I don't have a banana and therefore it doesn't taste good, which in a certain sense makes sense, but only if you're allowed to qualify something that doesn't exist.

An example that came up:

If we have

$f:(0,\infty)\mapsto\mathbb{R}$

$g:(-\infty,0)\mapsto\mathbb{R}$

then can $g \circ f$ be considered "not convex?"

Comment: To compose your $f$ and $g$ as $f\circ g$, we would need to know what the *range* of $g$ is.

Comment: You're right, my mistake, I've edited the question.

Comment: The domain of the composition $g\circ f$ is the set $$ \mathcal{D}(g) \cap f (\mathcal{D}(f)), $$ i.e. the intersection of the domain of $g$ with the range of $f$.  In your example, we still need to know where $f$ sends the positive half-line.  For example suppose that, $f(x) = \log(x)$ and $g(x) = \sqrt{-x}$.  Then $g\circ f(x) = \sqrt{\log(x)}$, which is perfectly well defined on the interval $(0,1)$.  Convexity is a different issue entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of convexity with which I am familiar is as follows (if you mean some other notion of convexity, please edit your question accordingly):

> Let $X$ be an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ (or, more generally, let $X$ be a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$).  Then we say that $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex if
>   $$ f(tx_0 + (1-t)x_1) \le tf(x_0) + (1-t)f(x_1) $$
>   for all $x_0,x_1 \in X$.

Essentially, this says that the line segment joining any two points in the graph of $f$ must be above the graph of $f$.  Note that this definition can be extended to more general domains—I'm not addressing that here.

Now, note that when you say that a function is "undefined," what you are actually saying is that the domain of that function is empty.  The emptyset is convex (vacuously), thus we can make sense of the definition of a convex function.  So suppose that $f : \emptyset \to \mathbb{R}$ (this function will have an empty range, but the doesn't stop us from making the codomain anything we like).  Since there are no $x_0, x_1\in\emptyset$, we make vacuously conclude that
$$ f(tx_0 + (1-t)x_1) \le t f(x_0) + (1-t)f(x_1) $$
for all possible $x_0, x_1 \in \emptyset$.  Therefore any function with an empty domain will be (vacuously) convex.

For your particular example, if $f : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g : \mathbb{R} \to (-\infty, 0)$, then the composition $f\circ g$ is a function with empty domain, i.e.
$$ f\circ g : \emptyset \to \mathbb{R}.$$
By the above argument, it is necessarily convex.

Comment: We could define convexity even in a non-convex domain by restricting ourselves to convex combinations which are in this domain. In this sense, any function defined on a two-point subset of $\Bbb R$ is convex, as well as any real function defined only on vertices of a triangle on the plane and so on.

Comment: @Xander

I've edited the question to make it more clear. The functions I intended to define are slightly different than what you had interpreted. Does the composition still behave in the manner you've described?

This question came up with my TA and at first gave me your exact explanation, but afterwards decided that it actually didn't have to do with vacuousness at all, and was rather a question of definition or lack thereof.

Comment: @JorgeZazueta When we say that a function is undefined (at a point, on a set, etc) we are making a statement about the domain of that function.  "$f$ is not defined at $a$" is **exactly the same statement** as "$a$ is not in the domain of $f$."

Answer (score -2):

Of course, convexity is a topological/geometric idea; even if the function is not regular you can define the concept.

**E.G.**

$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t.

- $f(x)=x^2$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$

is not regular but it is **Jensen-Convex**.

Comment: Ahem... Did you actually read the question? Because this does not seem to address the issue.

Comment: maybe, what is your interpretation?

Comment: For the sake of following the instructions in the post: let $f:(-\infty,0)\to (-\infty,0)$, $g:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$, $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x$. Is $f\circ g$ convex?

Comment: The function given in the above answer is not convex, because the graphs of discontinuous convex functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ are dense in the plane. Nevertheless  such $f$ is Jensen-convex on $\Bbb Q$ and $f$ is Jensen convex on $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$. But $2f(1)=2>f(1-\varepsilon)+f(1+\varepsilon)=0$ for irrational $\varepsilon$, so $f$ is not convex.

Comment: @szw1710 of course you're right, I've eliminated the $\notin \mathbb{Q}$, now is it ok? Thanks!

Comment: No, now it is still not correct. The function $f$ was corrected and now it is considered as $f:\Bbb Q\to\Bbb Q$. Then it is also not convex (consider convex combinations of $0, 1$ with  irrational scalars, take $t=\sqrt{2}/2$ for instance). It is Jensen-convex only, i.e. $2f((x+y)/2)\le f(x)+f(y).$

Comment: @szw1710 ok I was refering to Jensen-convexity, could you please exhibit an  example that works in general?

Comment: @gimusi Please explain what the example you need. If the answer is longer, I will create an answer, not a comment. Or... we could discuss it in a separate thread.

Comment: @szw1710 Never mind. Thanks!